# Persistence 1.0/2.0 XSD is down?

Tags: spring, persistence

I've created a spring project which I later deployed on glassfish, the ap is working at first. But when I added persistence.xml it took mins to be done with error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="sidoPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>myDatasource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When browse: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd, it wouldn't load.

Any idea or work around on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's related with the whole java.net, java.sun.com, project Kenai etc. being down because of the maintenance reasons.

https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/outage_on_java_net_apr